# How to get Method name in testng using @BeforeTest annotation

Tags: java, rest, testng, jxl

I'm working on rest API testing using Rest Assured and i'm using @BeforeTest annotation to call jxl data and write the results into it with the help of @Dataprovider annotation to pass test data.

But here I've total 4 api's and i want to read specific sheet for specific rest API based on method name in @Test annotation from different classes.

**Example:**

1.cardvalidation - validation Sheet
2.Purchase - purchase Sheet
3.Cancel - cancel purchase sheet

For Example if method name is cardvalidation  then i'll pick up only validation Sheet and so on for all 4 API's and i'm using Before Method annotation but it is writing results only for one row not for all test data rows.

Sample Code:

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void excelWriter(Method method) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException {

        File file = new File(inputFile);
        FileInputStream testFile = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook workBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(testFile);

        String methodName = method.getName();

        if(methodName.equals("validateTesting")) {
            sheet = workBook.getSheet("Validate_TestData");
        }else if(methodName.equals("purchaseTesting")) {
            sheet = workBook.getSheet("Purchase_TestData");
        }

        int rows = sheet.getRows();
        int columns = sheet.getColumns();

        String dataFile[][] = new String[rows][columns];

        File outputResults = new File(outputFile);
        // Write data into file
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputResults);
        // Create the workbook
        workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(fileOutputStream);

        if(methodName.equals("validateTesting")) {
            writablesh = workbookCopy.createSheet("Validate_Results", 0);
        }else if(methodName.equals("purchaseTesting")) {
            writablesh = workbookCopy.createSheet("Purchase_Results", 1);
        }


        // Copy all data from source file to Destination File

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                dataFile[i][j] = sheet.getCell(j, i).getContents();
                Label l = new Label(j, i, dataFile[i][j]);

                Label L2 = new Label(13, 0, "Results");
                writablesh.addCell(l);
                writablesh.addCell(L2);

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement interface `IInvokedMethodListener`, then You will have to implement following methods:

```
/**
 * A listener that gets invoked before and after a method is invoked by TestNG.
 * This listener will only be invoked for configuration and test methods.
 */

void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult);
void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult);
```

So this would suit Your needs.

So here is the example code to achieve this:

```
@Override
public synchronized void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) method.getTestMethod().getRealClass();
    Method method = method.getTestMethod().getMethod());

     // so each method You call is basically invoked, and it has to be processed.

}
```

Try with this. Hope it helps.